# React dynamic object creation

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to generate an object dynamically from forms. I ran into a problem when the next time a "Layout" component is added, it copies the properties of another "Layout". I can't figure out what could be the problem.

Link to CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-sky-3jhndf

I am sure that the solution to this problem can be simple. I will be glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**
If you add the first `Layout` and as a child element of the `Calculator` example, then the next time you add the Layout will also be with the `Calculator`child element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to copy your `Component`

```
const obj = Object.assign({ id: uuid() }, Component);
addElement(setElements, obj);
```

so when you edit your component, primitive data of `Component` also changed. So you need to [deep-clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) your component to avoid object mutation

```
const obj = Object.assign({ id: uuid() }, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Component)));
addElement(setElements, obj);
```

You can see in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-tree-rvpng2?file=/src/components/List/List.jsx:1133-1170)